# The implements of Integer numberOfTrailingZeros

Tags: java, performance, jvm, bit

I found the The implements of Integer numberOfTrailingZeros method in java as follows

```
public static int numberOfTrailingZeros(int i) {
    // HD, Figure 5-14
    int y;
    if (i == 0) return 32;
    int n = 31;
    y = i <<16; if (y != 0) { n = n -16; i = y; }
    y = i << 8; if (y != 0) { n = n - 8; i = y; }
    y = i << 4; if (y != 0) { n = n - 4; i = y; }
    y = i << 2; if (y != 0) { n = n - 2; i = y; }
    return n - ((i << 1) >>> 31);
}
```

It's take me a while to understand, here is my solution :

```
public static int numberOfTrailingZeros(int i) {
    if (i == 0) return 32;
    int num = 0;
    while ((i & 1) == 0) {
        i >>= 1;
        num ++;
    }
    return num;
}
```

My question is what's the better solution? How can I come up with those implements such as in JDK Integer bitCount,highestOneBit,rotateLeft etc methods?
as I know the JDK's numberOfTrailingZeros use less + opeartor, and will be having higher performance when dealing with '0x70000000','0x60000000', and anything else?

Comment: It seems like you could try some things to figure out which is better for you. Have you profiled them? Validated that they both output correct results for sample inputs and edge cases? My suspicion is that one implemented in the JDK is more well tested...

Comment: The JDK's algorithm is more-or-less binary searching for the end of the trailing zeroes.

Comment: `numberOfTrailingZeros` and `numberOfLeadingZeros` are one CPU clock cycle latent intrinsics.

Comment: @leventov Can you make it more clear for me?

Comment: @MarkSoul some methods from JDK are intrinsified, this means their Java implementaions is thrown away and in compiled code they are replaced with some specific machine code. You can find the list of all such methods here: http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=27010.0 For `numberOfLeadingZeros` (and Trailing) this means these method are replaced with a single machine instruction from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets , which takes only 1 CPU clock cycle, dozens times faster than expected compiled machine code from your (or JDK) pure Java implementation.

Comment: @leventov Thanks, appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the java JDK is doing is sort of a binary search in the number to find the number of trailing zeros. It tries to shift the number left by powers of 2 to see if the shifted number becomes 0. If it doesn't, there are some set bits that are too far to the right, so the method keeps that shifted number, decrements the final count, and tries again with the next smallest power of 2.